# How to take count of particular column with respective of the particular row in r

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

[image]

I want to calculate the total number of passes in each positions respectively and likewise the total number of fails in each positions respectively in R. How can  I achieve that?

[Here is the output of dput(head(data1))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHb24.jpg)
PS:fail ==fail lens_bubble

Comment: Please include a data example by pasting the output of `dput(head(df))` into your question.

Comment: @LAP .It can be found above

Comment: Don't post photos. Just copy/paste that in your question

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to perform this kind of analysis when the data is in a tidy format. You can learn more about what that means [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf).

First let's create an example of your data.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(327)

dta <- tibble(
  tool_number = 200:212,
  Err = sample(c("pass", "fail"), size = 13, replace = TRUE),

  pos01 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos02 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos03 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos04 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos05 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos06 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos07 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos08 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos09 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  pos10 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 13, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(seq(
    as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "day"
  ), 13)
)
```

The next step uses the `gather()` function to change the layout of your data to make it tidy.

```
dta <- gather(dta, key = position, value = value, pos01:pos10)
```

Now you can use the `group_by()` and `summarise()` functions to find the number of passes and fails for each position.

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(Err, position) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value))

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# # Groups:   Err [?]
# Err position count
# <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#   1  fail    pos01     2
# 2  fail    pos02     1
# 3  fail    pos03     3
# 4  fail    pos04     0
```

If you want to the data to look more like it did when you started, you can `spread()` the results.

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(Err, position) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value)) %>% 
  spread(key = Err, value = count)

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# position  fail  pass
# *    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1    pos01     2     4
# 2    pos02     1     2
# 3    pos03     3     4
# 4    pos04     0     5
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew about tidy data, but a base R solution would be

```
sapply(data1[, 3:12], function(x) sum(x[data1$Err == "pass"]))
```

and respectively

```
sapply(data1[, 3:12], function(x) sum(x[data1$Err == "fail"]))
```

Comment: In the rest of the data there are  numbers other than 1's and 0's like 30,20 which means the 30products are passed in position 1, 20 products failed in position 2 and so..on.Here i want to get the count of products in each positions which got passed and which got failed.

Comment: @ LAP Thank you so much...Here x means the column name right??

Comment: and i am getting this kind of output                                                                       
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,

Comment: Please copy the text from your second image into the question. I cannot copy the code from the picture and it is kinda difficult to come up with a working solution without having example data.